# java.util.LinkedList<ClassName> cannot be converted to ClassName

Tags: java, linked-list, return

I am on my way to learning java, so please bear with me on this one, even if its very simple to you.

I'm working with two LinkedLists:

```
private LinkedList<BloodDonor> x;
private LinkedList<BloodDonor> y;

public List()
{
    x = new LinkedList<>();
    y = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

I have a method called heroDonors that searches the LinkedList `x` to see if there are any people who donated blood more than 50 times. If so, that donor gets added to LinkedList `y` and removed from LinkList `x`. If no donors who donated more than 50 times are present, an empty LinkedList of `y` is returned.

I need the LinkedList `y` to be returned by the method, but I get the error  `java.util.LinkedList<BloodDonor> cannot be converted to BloodDonor`.

```
public BloodDonor heroDonors()
{
    int donations = 50;
    for (BloodDonor donor : x) {
        int number = donor.getNumberOfDonations();
        if (donations < number) {
            y.add(donor);
            x.remove(donor);
        }
        if (donations > number) {

        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Could anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: As the error states: you're returning `y` which is of type `LinkedList<BloodDonor>`, but in method header you've got `BloodDonor` as return type. Change `public BloodDonor heroDonors()` to `public LinkedList<BloodDonor> heroDonors()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a List of `BloodDonor`s you have to actually make your method of that type:

```
public LinkedList<BloodDonor> heroDonors() {
    LinkedList<BloodDonor> result = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

BTW: I think in this case you should not use a field `y` but declare a local variable on order to avoid side effects. You might also consider returning the base type `List<BloodDonor>` instead, this will better allow to use another collection if needed (and I would never call a application class `List`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realise I can have types of methods as `LinkedList<ClassName>`. I will definitely look more into that. And yes, I will work on my method and class naming. I will accept your answer as soon as I can!

Comment: Re: "I think in this case you should not use a field `y` but declare a local variable on order to avoid side effects": The problem with that is, this method is mutating `this.x` to remove the hero-donors. So the hero-donors *have* to be persisted in a field; otherwise, subsequent calls to `heroDonors()` will return an empty list. (I think you've correctly identified a design problem, but it's not *quite* so trivial to fix it . . .)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public BloodDonor heroDonors()
```

to

```
public List<BloodDonor> heroDonors()
```